# Can't enable Zend OpCache on AlmaLinux and PHP8

Tags: php, apache, opcache, php-8

I'm using AlmaLinux 8.4, and I'm trying to install Zend Opcache and verify that it's running.

In Easy Apache, `php8` and `php80-php-opcache` are installed. `php -1` shows Zend is not enabled, while `php -a` does, and `10-opcache.ini` is loaded. (I see that CLI is not enabled, but I don't need it.)

Apache and PHP-FPM have been restarted several times.

*Is this configuration correct?*

*How do I determine if Zend Opcode is actually running?*

---

`[root}# php -i` shows:

```
Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching => Disabled
Optimization => Disabled
SHM Cache => Enabled
File Cache => Disabled
JIT => On
Startup Failed => Opcode Caching is disabled for CLI
```

---

```
Loaded Configuration File => /opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/etc/php.ini
Additional .ini files parsed => /opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini
```

---

```
Core

PHP Version => 8.0.9

zend.assertions => -1 => -1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.exception_ignore_args => Off => Off
zend.exception_string_param_max_len => 15 => 15
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value
zend.signal_check => Off => Off
```

**The file /opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini shows**

```
Enable Zend OPcache extension module
zend_extension=opcache.so

; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=1

; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled for the CLI version of PHP
;opcache.enable_cli=0

; The OPcache shared memory storage size.
opcache.memory_consumption=128

; The amount of memory for interned strings in Mbytes.
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8

; The maximum number of keys (scripts) in the OPcache hash table.
; Only numbers between 200 and 100000 are allowed.
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
```

**php -a shows**

```
php > print_r(opcache_get_configuration());
Array
(
    [directives] => Array
        (
            [opcache.enable] => 1
            [opcache.enable_cli] => 
            [opcache.use_cwd] => 1
            [opcache.validate_timestamps] => 1
            [opcache.validate_permission] => 1
            [opcache.validate_root] => 
            [opcache.dups_fix] => 
            [opcache.revalidate_path] => 
            [opcache.log_verbosity_level] => 1
            [opcache.memory_consumption] => 134217728
            [opcache.interned_strings_buffer] => 8
            [opcache.max_accelerated_files] => 4000
            [opcache.max_wasted_percentage] => 0.05
            [opcache.consistency_checks] => 0
            [opcache.force_restart_timeout] => 180
            [opcache.revalidate_freq] => 2
            [opcache.preferred_memory_model] => 
            [opcache.blacklist_filename] => /opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/etc/php.d/opcache*.blacklist
            [opcache.max_file_size] => 0
            [opcache.error_log] => 
            [opcache.protect_memory] => 
            [opcache.save_comments] => 1
            [opcache.record_warnings] => 
            [opcache.enable_file_override] => 
            [opcache.optimization_level] => 2147401727
            [opcache.lockfile_path] => /tmp
            [opcache.file_cache] => 
            [opcache.file_cache_only] => 
            [opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks] => 1
            [opcache.file_update_protection] => 2
            [opcache.opt_debug_level] => 0
            [opcache.restrict_api] => 
            [opcache.huge_code_pages] => 
            [opcache.preload] => 
            [opcache.preload_user] => 
            [opcache.jit] => tracing
            [opcache.jit_buffer_size] => 0
            [opcache.jit_debug] => 0
            [opcache.jit_bisect_limit] => 0
            [opcache.jit_blacklist_root_trace] => 16
            [opcache.jit_blacklist_side_trace] => 8
            [opcache.jit_hot_func] => 127
            [opcache.jit_hot_loop] => 64
            [opcache.jit_hot_return] => 8
            [opcache.jit_hot_side_exit] => 8
            [opcache.jit_max_exit_counters] => 8192
            [opcache.jit_max_loop_unrolls] => 8
            [opcache.jit_max_polymorphic_calls] => 2
            [opcache.jit_max_recursive_calls] => 2
            [opcache.jit_max_recursive_returns] => 2
            [opcache.jit_max_root_traces] => 1024
            [opcache.jit_max_side_traces] => 128
            [opcache.jit_prof_threshold] => 0
        )

    [version] => Array
        (
            [version] => 8.0.9
            [opcache_product_name] => Zend OPcache
        )

    [blacklist] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: I tend to start with a couple of things, first is that `php -m` shows the `Zend OPcache` module (it can be loaded but not enabled), and second is go find the `opcache.so` and run `ldd opcache.so` and look for "not found" in case it didn't link properly (also common with php modules).

Comment: Thanks, `php -m` shows Zend OPcache, and running `ldd opcache.so` on the path `/home/virtfs/site/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/` shows `linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc01db8000) librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f078aacf000) libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f078a70a000) libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f078a4ea000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f078b029000).` So that appears to be OK. So why does `php -i` show disabled?

Answer (score 1):

To determine if the `opcache` is enabled and working and ensure that the JIT actually works, create a PHP script that's accessible via the browser and look at the output of `opcache_get_status()`.

Example PHP file can be:

```php
var_dump(opcache_get_status());
```

Example output when it is enabled is:

```
array(9) {
  ["opcache_enabled"]=>
  bool(true)
...
```

if the opcache extension is not installed or not enabled it will throw this error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function opcache_get_status()
```

Another option is that you print out your phpinfo and check for opcache in the output:

```php
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, as noted when I use `php -i` in the shell, I see `Opcode Caching => Disabled` and `Optimization => Disabled`, but putting `var_dump(opcache_get_status` in the site footer, I see `array(8) { ["opcache_enabled"]=> bool(true)` Why this difference?

Answer (score 0):

This determines if Zend OPCache is enabled for the CLI version of PHP

```
opcache.enable_cli=0
```

This may be the reason